# Flutter ListView maxscrollextent not working when list items height not consistent

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll

Please help on scrolling to the end of Flutter ListView,
The list is scrolling to end properly when items are with the same height, but when dynamic height I can't get it to work since months ago.
I tried almost everything to get the list to the end with different children heights like the sample below:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      double position = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      // _scrollController.jumpTo(position);
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        position,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    }
});
```

also tried putting the scrolltoend procedure inside timer with different durations, tried also jumpTo.. but no success.

Please help

Comment: Please elaborate on your question?

Comment: My question is, how to be able to always scroll to the end of list when list item heights are different may be containing images, videos or link preview data?

Comment: Whenever your images or videos load u need to call setState to notify the flutter engine of UI constraints changes. So in short add setState whenever a new image or video loads .